# How can I differentiate between two url requests from different HTML pages but with the same namespace in views.py?

Tags: html, django, url, web-development-server

I am creating a simple eBay like e-commerce website to get introduced with django. For removing an item from the watchlist, I placed two same links in two different HTML files, that is, I can either remove the item from the `watchlist.html` page or either from the item's page which was saved as `listing.html`. The url for both the pages look like this:

```
             <a href="{% url 'removeFromWatchlist' item.id %}"> Remove from watchlist </a>
```

Now, in my `views.py`, I want to render different pages on the basis of the request. For example, if someone clicked *Remove from watchlist* from `listing.html` then the link should redirect again to `listing.html` and same goes for the `watchlist.html`.

I tried `using request.resolver_match.view_name` but this gave me 'removeFromWatchlist' as the url namespace for both of these request is same.

Is there any way I can render two different HTML pages based on the origin of the url request?
Also, this is my second question here so apologies for incorrect or bad formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the **HTTP_REFERER** in the `request.META` attribute of the view to get the url that referred the request as so:

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def myview(request):
    ...
    return redirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER"))#Or however you prefer redirecting
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META